# Is there a difference between SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance and ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance

Tags: inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I am using version 4 of MVVM Light for Windows 8; it includes SimpleIOC. In various examples I sometimes see code to request an object based on SimpleIoc... and sometimes it is based on ServiceLocator...

Examples include:

userToken = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance();

mainVM = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance();

What is the difference between using SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance and ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance?

If there is no difference, does ServiceLocator just let me to have an option to change my mind about what IOC library I want to use? Does ServiceLocator just provide an additional layer of abstraction that is irrelevant if I am satified with SimpleIoc; or, does ServiceLocator perform some other useful magic that is not obvious to we IOC novices?

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Bounce... does anyone have a *real* answer?

Answer (score 10):

In your ViewModelLocator class you probably have the following line of code:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
  ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

`SimpleIoc` implements the `IServiceLocator` interface, which means that the `ServiceLocator` will use it as a DI source when invoked.

Edit:

OK, people want the "full fat and don't spare the cream" answer.  Here we go!

`ServiceLocator` is basically a shell.  The code for Service locator is:

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{
  private static ServiceLocatorProvider currentProvider;

  public static IServiceLocator Current
  {
    get
    {
      return ServiceLocator.currentProvider();
    }
  }

  public static void SetLocatorProvider(ServiceLocatorProvider newProvider)
  {
    ServiceLocator.currentProvider = newProvider;
  }
}
```

Yup, that's it.

What's `ServiceLocatorProvider`?  It's a delegate that returns an object that implements `IServiceLocator`.

`SimpleIoc` Implements `IServiceLocator`.  So when we do:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

We put our `SimpleIoc` object into the `ServiceLocator`. You can use either of these now because whether you call `ServiceLocator.Current` or `SimpleIoc.Default` you're returning the same object instance.

So, is there any difference between

```
userToken = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance();

mainVM = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance();
```

?

Nope.  None.  Both are singletons exposing a static property that is an implementation of `IServiceLocator`. As mentioned above, you're returning the same instance of object that implements `IServiceLocator` regardless of which you call.

The only reason why you might want to user `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance()` rather than `SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance()` is that at some point in the future you may change DI containers and, if you use `ServiceLocator`, you won't have to change your code.

Comment: Your answer is merely stating the obvious, my friend. What you said is implied in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mr. Bugnion's [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) on MSDN (in the section, "Various Ways to Register a Class"), I am presuming interchangeability of IoC providers is the one and only reason for using ServiceLocator.

As @FasterSolutions stated, SimpleIoc implements IServiceLocator, so I *suspect* the opposite to your statement about abstraction layers is true. I think you should use ServiceLocator, but this is without empirical evidence; maybe someone can prove me wrong (?)